# jQuery toggle duration not setting

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The example of it on a live site [is here](http://adonnelly759.students.cs.qub.ac.uk/thatch/menu.php)

The JS script I am working with is here:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.hideData').hide();

    $( '.toggleButton').click(function() {
        $(this).next().toggle(1000);
    });
});
```

The HTML document is includes PHP tags, however it doesn't render when click on the heading button I have set up via the div .toggleButton

```
<div class='toggleButton'>
<h1 class='head-font text-center head'>$result_array[$j]</h1>
</div>
<div class='hideData'>
<table class='table table-hover table-responsive'>
 <thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Item</th>
    <th class='text-right'>Price</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>

  <tr>
    <td>" . $name . " - <small>" . $description . "</small></td>
    <td class='text-right'>£" . $price . "</td>
  </tr>

</tbody>
```

Regardless of what number or speed I put into the toggle it does not change speed or animation?

Comment: code shown [works fine here](https://jsfiddle.net/nqh6nb7g/) and changing duration provides expected results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your website is adding jQuery twice and even when both files claim to be v3.2.1, the content of the scripts are not the same. You have:

- jquery-3_002.js
- jquery-3.js

The former is the good one. If you remove the script tag for **jquery-3.js** in your Html and reload the page, animation delay will start working:

```
<script src="Menu%20-%20The%20Old%20Thatch%20Inn_files/jquery-3.js"></script>
```